# What are the allowed ASCII characters via POST in HTTP requests?

Tags: httprequest, ascii

What ASCII characters are not allowed in HTTP requests (particularly via POST and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`)? *(one is '+')*

Comment: What kind of request (`POST`, `GET`)? In the request header or in the request body? What content type? What encoding? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14551194/841108) question is similar to yours (but not exactly the same)...

Comment: The direct answer to your question can be found by Googling `allowed characters in url` .... but you should probably elaborate what exactly went wrong at which point?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch as it is mentioned in the question, via POST, and ASCII encoding. It's a simple string parameter.

Comment: @Pekka웃 i was mostly thinking generally and i just brought an example why this is a question for me.

Comment: for `POST`, the `Content-type` is *very often* `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but it could be something else

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yes. i didn't know it's title, but my work is for submitting forms. i updated the question.

Comment: STFW gives [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type) wikipage, but the browser it taking care of that

Comment: I think you are missing my question here. simplified of my question: suppose it is a programming code. what characters should i replace?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the form is encoded with application/x-www-url-encoded, which is the default for HTML forms, the only characters you can definitely use are:

- 0-9
- a-z
- A-Z
- $ - _ . ! * ' ( ) , "

  "+" means space. Everything else can have a special meaning.

  If you are using multipart/form-data, then you can send anything anyhow. If you are using an HTML form, add the **enctype** property, like so:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: `+` has a special meaning for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding